# How to retrieve Error Messages (server side) with field names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am getting error list like this: **{ error: [ "Email is required", "First Name is required" ] }**

How I need to modify this, to get list with field names?

```
public static IEnumerable ExtractErrorMessages(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        return modelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
    }
```

The result must be like this: **{"FirstName": [ "First Name is required" ], "Email": [ "Email is required" ]}**

Comment: ModelStateDictionary does not contain a property like FieldName. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Curious and if with Values? How can i modify this to get value+err message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelState` can be used like a dictionary. It has a `ModelState.Keys` collection that tells you the field names.

```
IDictionary<string, string[]> errorsByField = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys) {
   if (ModelState[key].Errors.Any()) {
       var errors = ModelState[key].Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
       errorsByField.Add(key, errors);
   }
}
```

Note that the `Keys` are the names of the `<input>` bound by the ModelBinder, i.e. this corresponds to the name of the property in the ViewModel. This is not the `[DisplayName]` of this property. To get the DisplayName, you will have to use reflection on the ViewModel to retrieve the attribute value for this property, then translate it using the `ResourceManager`.

Comment: It works, but it's like Contacts[0].Email: ["The Email field is required."], is it possible to retrieve it without Conctacts[0]?

Comment: The keys are the names of the `<input>` bound by the ModelBinder. So if you have a list of contacts, and the email of the first contact is wrong, this is what you get. This format allows `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js` (included in MVC) to highlight the erroneous fields in the form. If you change this, you will break this feature. That being said, I guess you can always split the name at the dot `.` and only take the last part.

Comment: OK, I understand. But my erroneous fields are not highlighting, how to do that?

Comment: Here is a tutorial: [What is Unobtrusive Validation?](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/)